# Why Spring destory parts of bean(not all)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

the application started successful
[vm log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWgUN.png),
and after a while the shudownhook was triggered
[shutdown thread.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzLEG.png)
[shutdown thread.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpU3s.png),
i don't know what cause this problem , it didn't show any excetpion or something, and the strangest thing is the http service still can call.
[call log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjLfg.png)

how do i find out what cause this issue ?? and fix it . many thanks

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Edit your question to include the text as text.

Comment: And I don't mean nice links to the images -- copy and paste the text from your log files into your question, please.

Comment: Also what do you mean by destroying part of a bean?

Comment: There is some config wrong in your nacos ,   This line  ```failover switch is not found  ... ```  and others behind is occur by the package path com.alibaba.nacos, checkoout  your  nacos config and version , may  be some potential conflict with other dependency

Comment: thank you advise , i dont often post question on here,

Comment: sorry for my stupid question , i configured pod name in my "logback.xml" , and found out the shudtown log and other log come from different pod

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.